# Parsing JSON from String

Tags: javascript, json

Fiddle: https://mikethedj4.github.io/kodeWeave/editor/#6aade2727e9d2a1a20eea1e948fe7dbc

I'm having a little difficulty parsing JSON from a string. In my app I'm grabbing it in an onclick event

```
var data = {
  "files": JSON.parse($(selector).nextAll('textarea').val())
};
```

and storing the data into a textarea like so...

```
JSON.stringify(data)
```

To make the process easier for debugging I just used a simple string as it's replacement in the code below.

In console, it comes out as...

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'content' of undefined

I removed content from `var jsonSets = data.files["settings.json"].content;` and I was able to move past that but got...

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'siteTitle' of undefined

Which I planned on grabbing with .content. I'm not sure why I'm getting this error or even how to get past it.

Can anyone explain what I'm doing wrong?

How can I grab my `settings.json`. `siteTitle` value's string?

```js
var files = {
  "files": {
    "index.html": {
      "content": "&lt;div ng-app=\"App\" ng-controller=\"AppCtrl\" layout=\"row\" layout-fill ng-cloak&gt;\n  &lt;md-sidenav class=\"md-sidenav-left md-whiteframe-z2\" role=\"sidenav\" md-component-id=\"left\" md-is-locked-open=\"$mdMedia('gt-md')\"&gt;\n    &lt;md-toolbar class=\"md-tall md-hue-2\" layout-align=\"end end\"&gt;\n      &lt;div class=\"md-toolbar-tools\" layout layout-padding&gt;\n        &lt;md-icon&gt;{{data.user.icon}}&lt;/md-icon&gt;\n        &lt;div layout=\"column\" layout-padding&gt;\n          &lt;span class=\"md-body-2\"&gt;{{data.user.name}}&lt;/span&gt;\n          &lt;span class=\"md-caption\"&gt;{{data.user.email}}&lt;/span&gt;\n        &lt;/div&gt;\n        &lt;span flex&gt;&lt;/span&gt;\n        &lt;md-button class=\"md-icon-button\" aria-label=\"User Settings\" ng-click=\"toast('Logout')\"&gt;\n          &lt;md-icon&gt;more_vert&lt;/md-icon&gt;\n        &lt;/md-button&gt;\n      &lt;/div&gt;\n    &lt;/md-toolbar&gt;\n    &lt;md-content role=\"navigation\"&gt;\n      &lt;md-list ng-repeat=\"section in data.sidenav.sections\"&gt;\n        &lt;md-list-item ng-click=\"section.expand = !section.expand\"&gt;\n          &lt;p class=\"md-subheader md-primary\"&gt;{{section.name}}&lt;/p&gt;\n          &lt;span flex&gt;&lt;/span&gt;\n          &lt;md-icon class=\"md-primary md-icon-button\"&gt;{{section.expand ? 'arrow_drop_up' : 'arrow_drop_down'}}&lt;/md-icon&gt;\n        &lt;/md-list-item&gt;\n        &lt;md-list-item ng-show=\"section.expand\" ng-repeat=\"action in section.actions\" ng-click=\"toast(action.link)\"&gt;\n          &lt;md-icon&gt;{{action.icon}}&lt;/md-icon&gt;\n          &lt;p class=\"md-body-2\"&gt;{{action.name}}&lt;/p&gt;\n          &lt;span flex&gt;&lt;/span&gt;\n          &lt;md-icon&gt;chevron_right&lt;/md-icon&gt;\n        &lt;/md-list-item&gt;\n    &lt;/md-content&gt;\n  &lt;/md-sidenav&gt;\n  &lt;section layout=\"column\" role=\"main\" flex&gt;\n    &lt;md-toolbar role=\"toolbar\"&gt;\n      &lt;div class=\"md-toolbar-tools\"&gt;\n        &lt;md-button class=\"md-icon-button\" ng-click=\"toggleSidenav('left')\" hide-gt-md aria-label=\"Menu\"&gt;\n          &lt;md-icon&gt;menu&lt;/md-icon&gt;\n        &lt;/md-button&gt;\n        &lt;h4 class=\"md-title\"&gt;{{data.title}}&lt;/h4&gt;\n        &lt;span flex&gt;&lt;/span&gt;\n        &lt;md-button class=\"md-icon-button\" ng-repeat=\"button in data.toolbar.buttons\" aria-label={{button.name}} ng-click=\"toast(button.link)\"&gt;\n          &lt;md-icon&gt;{{button.icon}}&lt;/md-icon&gt;\n        &lt;/md-button&gt;\n        &lt;md-menu md-position-mode=\"target-right target\" ng-repeat=\"menu in data.toolbar.menus\"&gt;\n          &lt;md-button class=\"md-icon-button\" aria-label=\"{{menu.name}}\" ng-click=\"$mdOpenMenu($event)\"&gt;\n            &lt;md-icon&gt;{{menu.icon}}&lt;/md-icon&gt;\n          &lt;/md-button&gt;\n          &lt;md-menu-content width={{menu.width}}&gt;\n            &lt;md-subheader&gt;{{menu.name}}&lt;/md-subheader&gt;\n            &lt;md-menu-item ng-repeat=\"action in menu.actions\"&gt;\n              &lt;md-button layout-fill md-ink-ripple ng-click=\"toast(action.message)\"&gt;\n                &lt;md-icon md-class=\"{{action.error ? 'md-warn' : 'md-primary'}}\" md-menu-align-target&gt;{{action.completed ? 'done' : 'hourglass_empty'}}&lt;/md-icon&gt;\n                {{action.name}}\n              &lt;/md-button&gt;\n            &lt;/md-menu-item&gt;\n          &lt;/md-menu-content&gt;\n        &lt;/md-menu&gt;\n      &lt;/div&gt;\n    &lt;/md-toolbar&gt;\n    &lt;section id=\"content\" role=\"content\" layout=\"column\" layout-padding md-scroll-y&gt;\n      &lt;md-content class=\"md-whiteframe-z2\" ng-cloak&gt;\n        &lt;md-list ng-repeat=\"list in data.content.lists\"&gt;\n          &lt;div class=\"md-actions\" layout layout-align=\"end center\"&gt;\n            &lt;md-subheader class=\"md-no-sticky md-primary\"&gt;{{list.name}}&lt;/md-subheader&gt;\n            &lt;span flex&gt;&lt;/span&gt;\n            &lt;md-menu md-position-mode=\"target-right target\"&gt;\n              &lt;md-button class=\"md-icon-button\" aria-label=\"{{list.menu.name}}\" ng-click=\"$mdOpenMenu($event)\"&gt;\n                &lt;md-icon class=\"md-primary\"&gt;settings&lt;/md-icon&gt;\n              &lt;/md-button&gt;\n              &lt;md-menu-content width={{list.menu.width}}&gt;\n                &lt;md-subheader&gt;{{list.menu.name}}&lt;/md-subheader&gt;\n                &lt;md-menu-item ng-repeat=\"action in list.menu.actions\"&gt;\n                  &lt;md-button layout-fill md-ink-ripple ng-click=\"toastList(action.message)\"&gt;\n                    &lt;md-icon md-class=\"{{action.error ? 'md-warn' : 'md-primary'}}\" md-menu-align-target&gt;{{action.completed ? 'done' : 'hourglass_empty'}}&lt;/md-icon&gt;\n                    {{action.name}}\n                  &lt;/md-button&gt;\n                &lt;/md-menu-item&gt;\n              &lt;/md-menu-content&gt;\n            &lt;/md-menu&gt;\n          &lt;/div&gt;\n          &lt;md-divider&gt;&lt;/md-divider&gt;\n          &lt;md-list-item class=\"md-2-line\" ng-repeat=\"item in list.items\"&gt;\n            &lt;md-checkbox ng-click=\"toggle(item, selected)\"&gt;&lt;/md-checkbox&gt;\n            &lt;md-content class=\"md-list-item-text\" layout=\"column\"&gt;\n              &lt;h3 class=\"md-body-2\"&gt;{{item.name}}&lt;/h3&gt;\n              &lt;p class=\"md-caption\"&gt;{{item.description}}&lt;/p&gt;\n            &lt;/md-content&gt;\n            &lt;span flex&gt;&lt;/span&gt;\n            &lt;md-icon aria-label=\"Show Item\" ng-click=\"toast(item.link)\"&gt;chevron_right&lt;/md-icon&gt;\n          &lt;/md-list-item&gt;\n        &lt;/md-list&gt;\n      &lt;/md-content&gt;\n    &lt;/section&gt;\n  &lt;/section&gt;\n&lt;/div&gt;"
    }
    , "index.css": {
      "content": "body {\n  overflow: hidden;\n  background-color: #EEEEEE;\n}\n\nmd-whiteframe {\n  background: #fff;\n}\n\n#content {\n  padding: 24px;\n}\n\n"
    }
    , "index.js": {
      "content": "angular.module('App', [\n  'ngMaterial'\n]);\n\nangular.module('App').config(function($mdThemingProvider) {\n  $mdThemingProvider.theme('default').primaryPalette('indigo');\n})\n\nangular.module('App').controller('AppCtrl', function($scope, $mdSidenav, $mdToast) {\n  $scope.toggleSidenav = function(menu) {\n    $mdSidenav(menu).toggle();\n  }\n  $scope.toast = function(message) {\n    var toast = $mdToast.simple().content('You clicked ' + message).position('bottom right');\n    $mdToast.show(toast);\n  };\n  $scope.toastList = function(message) {\n    var toast = $mdToast.simple().content('You clicked ' + message + ' having selected ' + $scope.selected.length + ' item(s)').position('bottom right');\n    $mdToast.show(toast);\n  };\n  $scope.selected = [];\n  $scope.toggle = function(item, list) {\n    var idx = list.indexOf(item);\n    if (idx &gt; -1) list.splice(idx, 1);\n    else list.push(item);\n  };\n  $scope.data = {\n    title: 'Dashboard',\n    user: {\n      name: 'Angular Ninja',\n      email: 'angular@ninja.com',\n      icon: 'face'\n    },\n    toolbar: {\n      buttons: [{\n        name: 'Button 1',\n        icon: 'add',\n        link: 'Button 1'\n      }],\n      menus: [{\n        name: 'Menu 1',\n        icon: 'message',\n        width: '4',\n        actions: [{\n          name: 'Action 1',\n          message: 'Action 1',\n          completed: true,\n          error: true\n        }, {\n          name: 'Action 2',\n          message: 'Action 2',\n          completed: false,\n          error: false\n        }, {\n          name: 'Action 3',\n          message: 'Action 3',\n          completed: true,\n          error: true\n        }]\n      }]\n    },\n    sidenav: {\n      sections: [{\n        name: 'Section 1',\n        expand: true,\n        actions: [{\n          name: 'Action 1',\n          icon: 'settings',\n          link: 'Action 1'\n        }, {\n          name: 'Action 2',\n          icon: 'settings',\n          link: 'Action 2'\n        }]\n      }, {\n        name: 'Section 2',\n        expand: false,\n        actions: [{\n          name: 'Action 3',\n          icon: 'settings',\n          link: 'Action 3'\n        }]\n      }, {\n        name: 'Section 3',\n        expand: false,\n        actions: [{\n          name: 'Action 4',\n          icon: 'settings',\n          link: 'Action 4'\n        }, {\n          name: 'Action 5',\n          icon: 'settings',\n          link: 'Action 5'\n        }, {\n          name: 'Action 6',\n          icon: 'settings',\n          link: 'Action 6'\n        }]\n      }]\n    },\n    content: {\n      lists: [{\n        name: 'List 1',\n        menu: {\n          name: 'Menu 1',\n          icon: 'settings',\n          width: '4',\n          actions: [{\n            name: 'Action 1',\n            message: 'Action 1',\n            completed: true,\n            error: true\n          }]\n        },\n        items: [{\n          name: 'Item 1',\n          description: 'Description 1',\n          link: 'Item 1'\n        }, {\n          name: 'Item 2',\n          description: 'Description 2',\n          link: 'Item 2'\n        }, {\n          name: 'Item 3',\n          description: 'Description 3',\n          link: 'Item 3'\n        }]\n      }]\n    }\n  }\n});"
    }
    , "libraries.json": {
      "content": "{\"alertify\":false,\"angular\":false,\"angularmaterial\":false,\"animatecss\":false,\"backbone\":false,\"bootstrap\":false,\"chartjs\":false,\"codemirror\":false,\"createjs\":false,\"d3\":false,\"dojo\":false,\"enhance\":false,\"fabricjs\":false,\"foundation\":false,\"handlebars\":false,\"hintcss\":false,\"immutable\":false,\"jarallax\":false,\"jquery\":false,\"jqueryui\":false,\"jquerytools\":false,\"jqxsplitter\":false,\"jszip\":false,\"kinetic\":false,\"knockout\":false,\"lodash\":false,\"mdl\":false,\"modernizer\":false,\"moment\":false,\"momenttimezone\":false,\"mootools\":false,\"normalize\":false,\"paperjs\":false,\"polyui\":false,\"prefixfree\":false,\"processingjs\":false,\"prototypejs\":false,\"qooxdoo\":false,\"react\":false,\"raphael\":false,\"requirejs\":false,\"showdown\":false,\"scriptaculous\":false,\"smoothscroll\":false,\"snapsvg\":false,\"svgjs\":false,\"threejs\":false,\"uikit\":false,\"underscorejs\":false,\"vue\":false,\"webfontloader\":false,\"yui\":false,\"zepto\":false}"
    }
    , "settings.json": {
      "content": "{\"siteTitle\":\"Angular Material\",\"WeaveVersion\":\"0.1\",\"editorFontSize\":\"14\",\"description\":\"Angular Material Test\",\"author\":\"Someone\"}"
    }
  }
}
var data = {
  "files": files
};
var jsonSets = data.files["settings.json"].content;

console.log(jsonSets.siteTitle);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a missing property (`files`) and you need to parse the JSON the value to convert it into an object:

```js
var files = {
  "files": {
    "index.html": {
      "content": "&lt;div ng-app=\"App\" ng-controller=\"AppCtrl\" layout=\"row\" layout-fill ng-cloak&gt;\n  &lt;md-sidenav class=\"md-sidenav-left md-whiteframe-z2\" role=\"sidenav\" md-component-id=\"left\" md-is-locked-open=\"$mdMedia('gt-md')\"&gt;\n    &lt;md-toolbar class=\"md-tall md-hue-2\" layout-align=\"end end\"&gt;\n      &lt;div class=\"md-toolbar-tools\" layout layout-padding&gt;\n        &lt;md-icon&gt;{{data.user.icon}}&lt;/md-icon&gt;\n        &lt;div layout=\"column\" layout-padding&gt;\n          &lt;span class=\"md-body-2\"&gt;{{data.user.name}}&lt;/span&gt;\n          &lt;span class=\"md-caption\"&gt;{{data.user.email}}&lt;/span&gt;\n        &lt;/div&gt;\n        &lt;span flex&gt;&lt;/span&gt;\n        &lt;md-button class=\"md-icon-button\" aria-label=\"User Settings\" ng-click=\"toast('Logout')\"&gt;\n          &lt;md-icon&gt;more_vert&lt;/md-icon&gt;\n        &lt;/md-button&gt;\n      &lt;/div&gt;\n    &lt;/md-toolbar&gt;\n    &lt;md-content role=\"navigation\"&gt;\n      &lt;md-list ng-repeat=\"section in data.sidenav.sections\"&gt;\n        &lt;md-list-item ng-click=\"section.expand = !section.expand\"&gt;\n          &lt;p class=\"md-subheader md-primary\"&gt;{{section.name}}&lt;/p&gt;\n          &lt;span flex&gt;&lt;/span&gt;\n          &lt;md-icon class=\"md-primary md-icon-button\"&gt;{{section.expand ? 'arrow_drop_up' : 'arrow_drop_down'}}&lt;/md-icon&gt;\n        &lt;/md-list-item&gt;\n        &lt;md-list-item ng-show=\"section.expand\" ng-repeat=\"action in section.actions\" ng-click=\"toast(action.link)\"&gt;\n          &lt;md-icon&gt;{{action.icon}}&lt;/md-icon&gt;\n          &lt;p class=\"md-body-2\"&gt;{{action.name}}&lt;/p&gt;\n          &lt;span flex&gt;&lt;/span&gt;\n          &lt;md-icon&gt;chevron_right&lt;/md-icon&gt;\n        &lt;/md-list-item&gt;\n    &lt;/md-content&gt;\n  &lt;/md-sidenav&gt;\n  &lt;section layout=\"column\" role=\"main\" flex&gt;\n    &lt;md-toolbar role=\"toolbar\"&gt;\n      &lt;div class=\"md-toolbar-tools\"&gt;\n        &lt;md-button class=\"md-icon-button\" ng-click=\"toggleSidenav('left')\" hide-gt-md aria-label=\"Menu\"&gt;\n          &lt;md-icon&gt;menu&lt;/md-icon&gt;\n        &lt;/md-button&gt;\n        &lt;h4 class=\"md-title\"&gt;{{data.title}}&lt;/h4&gt;\n        &lt;span flex&gt;&lt;/span&gt;\n        &lt;md-button class=\"md-icon-button\" ng-repeat=\"button in data.toolbar.buttons\" aria-label={{button.name}} ng-click=\"toast(button.link)\"&gt;\n          &lt;md-icon&gt;{{button.icon}}&lt;/md-icon&gt;\n        &lt;/md-button&gt;\n        &lt;md-menu md-position-mode=\"target-right target\" ng-repeat=\"menu in data.toolbar.menus\"&gt;\n          &lt;md-button class=\"md-icon-button\" aria-label=\"{{menu.name}}\" ng-click=\"$mdOpenMenu($event)\"&gt;\n            &lt;md-icon&gt;{{menu.icon}}&lt;/md-icon&gt;\n          &lt;/md-button&gt;\n          &lt;md-menu-content width={{menu.width}}&gt;\n            &lt;md-subheader&gt;{{menu.name}}&lt;/md-subheader&gt;\n            &lt;md-menu-item ng-repeat=\"action in menu.actions\"&gt;\n              &lt;md-button layout-fill md-ink-ripple ng-click=\"toast(action.message)\"&gt;\n                &lt;md-icon md-class=\"{{action.error ? 'md-warn' : 'md-primary'}}\" md-menu-align-target&gt;{{action.completed ? 'done' : 'hourglass_empty'}}&lt;/md-icon&gt;\n                {{action.name}}\n              &lt;/md-button&gt;\n            &lt;/md-menu-item&gt;\n          &lt;/md-menu-content&gt;\n        &lt;/md-menu&gt;\n      &lt;/div&gt;\n    &lt;/md-toolbar&gt;\n    &lt;section id=\"content\" role=\"content\" layout=\"column\" layout-padding md-scroll-y&gt;\n      &lt;md-content class=\"md-whiteframe-z2\" ng-cloak&gt;\n        &lt;md-list ng-repeat=\"list in data.content.lists\"&gt;\n          &lt;div class=\"md-actions\" layout layout-align=\"end center\"&gt;\n            &lt;md-subheader class=\"md-no-sticky md-primary\"&gt;{{list.name}}&lt;/md-subheader&gt;\n            &lt;span flex&gt;&lt;/span&gt;\n            &lt;md-menu md-position-mode=\"target-right target\"&gt;\n              &lt;md-button class=\"md-icon-button\" aria-label=\"{{list.menu.name}}\" ng-click=\"$mdOpenMenu($event)\"&gt;\n                &lt;md-icon class=\"md-primary\"&gt;settings&lt;/md-icon&gt;\n              &lt;/md-button&gt;\n              &lt;md-menu-content width={{list.menu.width}}&gt;\n                &lt;md-subheader&gt;{{list.menu.name}}&lt;/md-subheader&gt;\n                &lt;md-menu-item ng-repeat=\"action in list.menu.actions\"&gt;\n                  &lt;md-button layout-fill md-ink-ripple ng-click=\"toastList(action.message)\"&gt;\n                    &lt;md-icon md-class=\"{{action.error ? 'md-warn' : 'md-primary'}}\" md-menu-align-target&gt;{{action.completed ? 'done' : 'hourglass_empty'}}&lt;/md-icon&gt;\n                    {{action.name}}\n                  &lt;/md-button&gt;\n                &lt;/md-menu-item&gt;\n              &lt;/md-menu-content&gt;\n            &lt;/md-menu&gt;\n          &lt;/div&gt;\n          &lt;md-divider&gt;&lt;/md-divider&gt;\n          &lt;md-list-item class=\"md-2-line\" ng-repeat=\"item in list.items\"&gt;\n            &lt;md-checkbox ng-click=\"toggle(item, selected)\"&gt;&lt;/md-checkbox&gt;\n            &lt;md-content class=\"md-list-item-text\" layout=\"column\"&gt;\n              &lt;h3 class=\"md-body-2\"&gt;{{item.name}}&lt;/h3&gt;\n              &lt;p class=\"md-caption\"&gt;{{item.description}}&lt;/p&gt;\n            &lt;/md-content&gt;\n            &lt;span flex&gt;&lt;/span&gt;\n            &lt;md-icon aria-label=\"Show Item\" ng-click=\"toast(item.link)\"&gt;chevron_right&lt;/md-icon&gt;\n          &lt;/md-list-item&gt;\n        &lt;/md-list&gt;\n      &lt;/md-content&gt;\n    &lt;/section&gt;\n  &lt;/section&gt;\n&lt;/div&gt;"
    }
    , "index.css": {
      "content": "body {\n  overflow: hidden;\n  background-color: #EEEEEE;\n}\n\nmd-whiteframe {\n  background: #fff;\n}\n\n#content {\n  padding: 24px;\n}\n\n"
    }
    , "index.js": {
      "content": "angular.module('App', [\n  'ngMaterial'\n]);\n\nangular.module('App').config(function($mdThemingProvider) {\n  $mdThemingProvider.theme('default').primaryPalette('indigo');\n})\n\nangular.module('App').controller('AppCtrl', function($scope, $mdSidenav, $mdToast) {\n  $scope.toggleSidenav = function(menu) {\n    $mdSidenav(menu).toggle();\n  }\n  $scope.toast = function(message) {\n    var toast = $mdToast.simple().content('You clicked ' + message).position('bottom right');\n    $mdToast.show(toast);\n  };\n  $scope.toastList = function(message) {\n    var toast = $mdToast.simple().content('You clicked ' + message + ' having selected ' + $scope.selected.length + ' item(s)').position('bottom right');\n    $mdToast.show(toast);\n  };\n  $scope.selected = [];\n  $scope.toggle = function(item, list) {\n    var idx = list.indexOf(item);\n    if (idx &gt; -1) list.splice(idx, 1);\n    else list.push(item);\n  };\n  $scope.data = {\n    title: 'Dashboard',\n    user: {\n      name: 'Angular Ninja',\n      email: 'angular@ninja.com',\n      icon: 'face'\n    },\n    toolbar: {\n      buttons: [{\n        name: 'Button 1',\n        icon: 'add',\n        link: 'Button 1'\n      }],\n      menus: [{\n        name: 'Menu 1',\n        icon: 'message',\n        width: '4',\n        actions: [{\n          name: 'Action 1',\n          message: 'Action 1',\n          completed: true,\n          error: true\n        }, {\n          name: 'Action 2',\n          message: 'Action 2',\n          completed: false,\n          error: false\n        }, {\n          name: 'Action 3',\n          message: 'Action 3',\n          completed: true,\n          error: true\n        }]\n      }]\n    },\n    sidenav: {\n      sections: [{\n        name: 'Section 1',\n        expand: true,\n        actions: [{\n          name: 'Action 1',\n          icon: 'settings',\n          link: 'Action 1'\n        }, {\n          name: 'Action 2',\n          icon: 'settings',\n          link: 'Action 2'\n        }]\n      }, {\n        name: 'Section 2',\n        expand: false,\n        actions: [{\n          name: 'Action 3',\n          icon: 'settings',\n          link: 'Action 3'\n        }]\n      }, {\n        name: 'Section 3',\n        expand: false,\n        actions: [{\n          name: 'Action 4',\n          icon: 'settings',\n          link: 'Action 4'\n        }, {\n          name: 'Action 5',\n          icon: 'settings',\n          link: 'Action 5'\n        }, {\n          name: 'Action 6',\n          icon: 'settings',\n          link: 'Action 6'\n        }]\n      }]\n    },\n    content: {\n      lists: [{\n        name: 'List 1',\n        menu: {\n          name: 'Menu 1',\n          icon: 'settings',\n          width: '4',\n          actions: [{\n            name: 'Action 1',\n            message: 'Action 1',\n            completed: true,\n            error: true\n          }]\n        },\n        items: [{\n          name: 'Item 1',\n          description: 'Description 1',\n          link: 'Item 1'\n        }, {\n          name: 'Item 2',\n          description: 'Description 2',\n          link: 'Item 2'\n        }, {\n          name: 'Item 3',\n          description: 'Description 3',\n          link: 'Item 3'\n        }]\n      }]\n    }\n  }\n});"
    }
    , "libraries.json": {
      "content": "{\"alertify\":false,\"angular\":false,\"angularmaterial\":false,\"animatecss\":false,\"backbone\":false,\"bootstrap\":false,\"chartjs\":false,\"codemirror\":false,\"createjs\":false,\"d3\":false,\"dojo\":false,\"enhance\":false,\"fabricjs\":false,\"foundation\":false,\"handlebars\":false,\"hintcss\":false,\"immutable\":false,\"jarallax\":false,\"jquery\":false,\"jqueryui\":false,\"jquerytools\":false,\"jqxsplitter\":false,\"jszip\":false,\"kinetic\":false,\"knockout\":false,\"lodash\":false,\"mdl\":false,\"modernizer\":false,\"moment\":false,\"momenttimezone\":false,\"mootools\":false,\"normalize\":false,\"paperjs\":false,\"polyui\":false,\"prefixfree\":false,\"processingjs\":false,\"prototypejs\":false,\"qooxdoo\":false,\"react\":false,\"raphael\":false,\"requirejs\":false,\"showdown\":false,\"scriptaculous\":false,\"smoothscroll\":false,\"snapsvg\":false,\"svgjs\":false,\"threejs\":false,\"uikit\":false,\"underscorejs\":false,\"vue\":false,\"webfontloader\":false,\"yui\":false,\"zepto\":false}"
    }
    , "settings.json": {
      "content": "{\"siteTitle\":\"Angular Material\",\"WeaveVersion\":\"0.1\",\"editorFontSize\":\"14\",\"description\":\"Angular Material Test\",\"author\":\"Someone\"}"
    }
  }
}
var data = {
  "files": files
};
var jsonSets = JSON.parse(data.files.files["settings.json"].content);

console.log(jsonSets.siteTitle);
```

You could also just use the `files` object directly:

```
var jsonSets = JSON.parse(files.files["settings.json"].content);
```

Answer (score 3):

You forgot that the `files` variable also has a top-level **key** called files, which you also need to reference. As such, you'll need to use `data.files["files"]["libraries.json"].content`.

You'll also need to **parse** the JSON stored within `content`.

I've trimmed down the `content` to make the following example clearer:

```js
var files = {
  "files": {
    "index.html": {
      "content": "test"
    },
    "index.js": {
      "content": "test"
    },
    "libraries.json": {
      "content": "test"
    },
    "settings.json": {
      "content": "{\"siteTitle\":\"Angular Material\"}"
    }
  }
};
var data = {
  "files": files
};

var htmlVal = data.files["files"]["index.html"];
var jadeVal = data.files["files"]["index.jade"];
var cssVal = data.files["files"]["index.css"];
var stylusVal = data.files["files"]["index.styl"];
var lessVal = data.files["files"]["index.less"];
var jsVal = data.files["files"]["index.js"];
var coffeeVal = data.files["files"]["index.coffee"];
var typescriptVal = data.files["files"]["index.ts"];
var babelVal = data.files["files"]["index.jsx"];
var mdVal = data.files["files"]["README.md"];
var jsonSets = data.files["files"]["settings.json"].content;
var jsonLibs = data.files["files"]["libraries.json"].content;

// Return font settings from json
var siteTitle = jsonSets.siteTitle;
var WeaveVersion = jsonSets.version;
var editorFontSize = jsonSets.editorFontSize;
var WeaveDesc = jsonSets.description;
var WeaveAuthor = jsonSets.author;

console.log(JSON.parse(jsonSets).siteTitle);
```

Hope this helps! :)

Answer (score 2):

Since the value of `data.files["settings.json"].content` is a JSON string, you have to parse it to use it as an object.

Also, since since the content you want is in `files.files`, and you set `data.files = files`, you need to access it as `data.files.files`.

```js
var files = {
  "files": {
    "index.html": {
      "content": "&lt;div ng-app=\"App\" ng-controller=\"AppCtrl\" layout=\"row\" layout-fill ng-cloak&gt;\n  &lt;md-sidenav class=\"md-sidenav-left md-whiteframe-z2\" role=\"sidenav\" md-component-id=\"left\" md-is-locked-open=\"$mdMedia('gt-md')\"&gt;\n    &lt;md-toolbar class=\"md-tall md-hue-2\" layout-align=\"end end\"&gt;\n      &lt;div class=\"md-toolbar-tools\" layout layout-padding&gt;\n        &lt;md-icon&gt;{{data.user.icon}}&lt;/md-icon&gt;\n        &lt;div layout=\"column\" layout-padding&gt;\n          &lt;span class=\"md-body-2\"&gt;{{data.user.name}}&lt;/span&gt;\n          &lt;span class=\"md-caption\"&gt;{{data.user.email}}&lt;/span&gt;\n        &lt;/div&gt;\n        &lt;span flex&gt;&lt;/span&gt;\n        &lt;md-button class=\"md-icon-button\" aria-label=\"User Settings\" ng-click=\"toast('Logout')\"&gt;\n          &lt;md-icon&gt;more_vert&lt;/md-icon&gt;\n        &lt;/md-button&gt;\n      &lt;/div&gt;\n    &lt;/md-toolbar&gt;\n    &lt;md-content role=\"navigation\"&gt;\n      &lt;md-list ng-repeat=\"section in data.sidenav.sections\"&gt;\n        &lt;md-list-item ng-click=\"section.expand = !section.expand\"&gt;\n          &lt;p class=\"md-subheader md-primary\"&gt;{{section.name}}&lt;/p&gt;\n          &lt;span flex&gt;&lt;/span&gt;\n          &lt;md-icon class=\"md-primary md-icon-button\"&gt;{{section.expand ? 'arrow_drop_up' : 'arrow_drop_down'}}&lt;/md-icon&gt;\n        &lt;/md-list-item&gt;\n        &lt;md-list-item ng-show=\"section.expand\" ng-repeat=\"action in section.actions\" ng-click=\"toast(action.link)\"&gt;\n          &lt;md-icon&gt;{{action.icon}}&lt;/md-icon&gt;\n          &lt;p class=\"md-body-2\"&gt;{{action.name}}&lt;/p&gt;\n          &lt;span flex&gt;&lt;/span&gt;\n          &lt;md-icon&gt;chevron_right&lt;/md-icon&gt;\n        &lt;/md-list-item&gt;\n    &lt;/md-content&gt;\n  &lt;/md-sidenav&gt;\n  &lt;section layout=\"column\" role=\"main\" flex&gt;\n    &lt;md-toolbar role=\"toolbar\"&gt;\n      &lt;div class=\"md-toolbar-tools\"&gt;\n        &lt;md-button class=\"md-icon-button\" ng-click=\"toggleSidenav('left')\" hide-gt-md aria-label=\"Menu\"&gt;\n          &lt;md-icon&gt;menu&lt;/md-icon&gt;\n        &lt;/md-button&gt;\n        &lt;h4 class=\"md-title\"&gt;{{data.title}}&lt;/h4&gt;\n        &lt;span flex&gt;&lt;/span&gt;\n        &lt;md-button class=\"md-icon-button\" ng-repeat=\"button in data.toolbar.buttons\" aria-label={{button.name}} ng-click=\"toast(button.link)\"&gt;\n          &lt;md-icon&gt;{{button.icon}}&lt;/md-icon&gt;\n        &lt;/md-button&gt;\n        &lt;md-menu md-position-mode=\"target-right target\" ng-repeat=\"menu in data.toolbar.menus\"&gt;\n          &lt;md-button class=\"md-icon-button\" aria-label=\"{{menu.name}}\" ng-click=\"$mdOpenMenu($event)\"&gt;\n            &lt;md-icon&gt;{{menu.icon}}&lt;/md-icon&gt;\n          &lt;/md-button&gt;\n          &lt;md-menu-content width={{menu.width}}&gt;\n            &lt;md-subheader&gt;{{menu.name}}&lt;/md-subheader&gt;\n            &lt;md-menu-item ng-repeat=\"action in menu.actions\"&gt;\n              &lt;md-button layout-fill md-ink-ripple ng-click=\"toast(action.message)\"&gt;\n                &lt;md-icon md-class=\"{{action.error ? 'md-warn' : 'md-primary'}}\" md-menu-align-target&gt;{{action.completed ? 'done' : 'hourglass_empty'}}&lt;/md-icon&gt;\n                {{action.name}}\n              &lt;/md-button&gt;\n            &lt;/md-menu-item&gt;\n          &lt;/md-menu-content&gt;\n        &lt;/md-menu&gt;\n      &lt;/div&gt;\n    &lt;/md-toolbar&gt;\n    &lt;section id=\"content\" role=\"content\" layout=\"column\" layout-padding md-scroll-y&gt;\n      &lt;md-content class=\"md-whiteframe-z2\" ng-cloak&gt;\n        &lt;md-list ng-repeat=\"list in data.content.lists\"&gt;\n          &lt;div class=\"md-actions\" layout layout-align=\"end center\"&gt;\n            &lt;md-subheader class=\"md-no-sticky md-primary\"&gt;{{list.name}}&lt;/md-subheader&gt;\n            &lt;span flex&gt;&lt;/span&gt;\n            &lt;md-menu md-position-mode=\"target-right target\"&gt;\n              &lt;md-button class=\"md-icon-button\" aria-label=\"{{list.menu.name}}\" ng-click=\"$mdOpenMenu($event)\"&gt;\n                &lt;md-icon class=\"md-primary\"&gt;settings&lt;/md-icon&gt;\n              &lt;/md-button&gt;\n              &lt;md-menu-content width={{list.menu.width}}&gt;\n                &lt;md-subheader&gt;{{list.menu.name}}&lt;/md-subheader&gt;\n                &lt;md-menu-item ng-repeat=\"action in list.menu.actions\"&gt;\n                  &lt;md-button layout-fill md-ink-ripple ng-click=\"toastList(action.message)\"&gt;\n                    &lt;md-icon md-class=\"{{action.error ? 'md-warn' : 'md-primary'}}\" md-menu-align-target&gt;{{action.completed ? 'done' : 'hourglass_empty'}}&lt;/md-icon&gt;\n                    {{action.name}}\n                  &lt;/md-button&gt;\n                &lt;/md-menu-item&gt;\n              &lt;/md-menu-content&gt;\n            &lt;/md-menu&gt;\n          &lt;/div&gt;\n          &lt;md-divider&gt;&lt;/md-divider&gt;\n          &lt;md-list-item class=\"md-2-line\" ng-repeat=\"item in list.items\"&gt;\n            &lt;md-checkbox ng-click=\"toggle(item, selected)\"&gt;&lt;/md-checkbox&gt;\n            &lt;md-content class=\"md-list-item-text\" layout=\"column\"&gt;\n              &lt;h3 class=\"md-body-2\"&gt;{{item.name}}&lt;/h3&gt;\n              &lt;p class=\"md-caption\"&gt;{{item.description}}&lt;/p&gt;\n            &lt;/md-content&gt;\n            &lt;span flex&gt;&lt;/span&gt;\n            &lt;md-icon aria-label=\"Show Item\" ng-click=\"toast(item.link)\"&gt;chevron_right&lt;/md-icon&gt;\n          &lt;/md-list-item&gt;\n        &lt;/md-list&gt;\n      &lt;/md-content&gt;\n    &lt;/section&gt;\n  &lt;/section&gt;\n&lt;/div&gt;"
    }
    , "index.css": {
      "content": "body {\n  overflow: hidden;\n  background-color: #EEEEEE;\n}\n\nmd-whiteframe {\n  background: #fff;\n}\n\n#content {\n  padding: 24px;\n}\n\n"
    }
    , "index.js": {
      "content": "angular.module('App', [\n  'ngMaterial'\n]);\n\nangular.module('App').config(function($mdThemingProvider) {\n  $mdThemingProvider.theme('default').primaryPalette('indigo');\n})\n\nangular.module('App').controller('AppCtrl', function($scope, $mdSidenav, $mdToast) {\n  $scope.toggleSidenav = function(menu) {\n    $mdSidenav(menu).toggle();\n  }\n  $scope.toast = function(message) {\n    var toast = $mdToast.simple().content('You clicked ' + message).position('bottom right');\n    $mdToast.show(toast);\n  };\n  $scope.toastList = function(message) {\n    var toast = $mdToast.simple().content('You clicked ' + message + ' having selected ' + $scope.selected.length + ' item(s)').position('bottom right');\n    $mdToast.show(toast);\n  };\n  $scope.selected = [];\n  $scope.toggle = function(item, list) {\n    var idx = list.indexOf(item);\n    if (idx &gt; -1) list.splice(idx, 1);\n    else list.push(item);\n  };\n  $scope.data = {\n    title: 'Dashboard',\n    user: {\n      name: 'Angular Ninja',\n      email: 'angular@ninja.com',\n      icon: 'face'\n    },\n    toolbar: {\n      buttons: [{\n        name: 'Button 1',\n        icon: 'add',\n        link: 'Button 1'\n      }],\n      menus: [{\n        name: 'Menu 1',\n        icon: 'message',\n        width: '4',\n        actions: [{\n          name: 'Action 1',\n          message: 'Action 1',\n          completed: true,\n          error: true\n        }, {\n          name: 'Action 2',\n          message: 'Action 2',\n          completed: false,\n          error: false\n        }, {\n          name: 'Action 3',\n          message: 'Action 3',\n          completed: true,\n          error: true\n        }]\n      }]\n    },\n    sidenav: {\n      sections: [{\n        name: 'Section 1',\n        expand: true,\n        actions: [{\n          name: 'Action 1',\n          icon: 'settings',\n          link: 'Action 1'\n        }, {\n          name: 'Action 2',\n          icon: 'settings',\n          link: 'Action 2'\n        }]\n      }, {\n        name: 'Section 2',\n        expand: false,\n        actions: [{\n          name: 'Action 3',\n          icon: 'settings',\n          link: 'Action 3'\n        }]\n      }, {\n        name: 'Section 3',\n        expand: false,\n        actions: [{\n          name: 'Action 4',\n          icon: 'settings',\n          link: 'Action 4'\n        }, {\n          name: 'Action 5',\n          icon: 'settings',\n          link: 'Action 5'\n        }, {\n          name: 'Action 6',\n          icon: 'settings',\n          link: 'Action 6'\n        }]\n      }]\n    },\n    content: {\n      lists: [{\n        name: 'List 1',\n        menu: {\n          name: 'Menu 1',\n          icon: 'settings',\n          width: '4',\n          actions: [{\n            name: 'Action 1',\n            message: 'Action 1',\n            completed: true,\n            error: true\n          }]\n        },\n        items: [{\n          name: 'Item 1',\n          description: 'Description 1',\n          link: 'Item 1'\n        }, {\n          name: 'Item 2',\n          description: 'Description 2',\n          link: 'Item 2'\n        }, {\n          name: 'Item 3',\n          description: 'Description 3',\n          link: 'Item 3'\n        }]\n      }]\n    }\n  }\n});"
    }
    , "libraries.json": {
      "content": "{\"alertify\":false,\"angular\":false,\"angularmaterial\":false,\"animatecss\":false,\"backbone\":false,\"bootstrap\":false,\"chartjs\":false,\"codemirror\":false,\"createjs\":false,\"d3\":false,\"dojo\":false,\"enhance\":false,\"fabricjs\":false,\"foundation\":false,\"handlebars\":false,\"hintcss\":false,\"immutable\":false,\"jarallax\":false,\"jquery\":false,\"jqueryui\":false,\"jquerytools\":false,\"jqxsplitter\":false,\"jszip\":false,\"kinetic\":false,\"knockout\":false,\"lodash\":false,\"mdl\":false,\"modernizer\":false,\"moment\":false,\"momenttimezone\":false,\"mootools\":false,\"normalize\":false,\"paperjs\":false,\"polyui\":false,\"prefixfree\":false,\"processingjs\":false,\"prototypejs\":false,\"qooxdoo\":false,\"react\":false,\"raphael\":false,\"requirejs\":false,\"showdown\":false,\"scriptaculous\":false,\"smoothscroll\":false,\"snapsvg\":false,\"svgjs\":false,\"threejs\":false,\"uikit\":false,\"underscorejs\":false,\"vue\":false,\"webfontloader\":false,\"yui\":false,\"zepto\":false}"
    }
    , "settings.json": {
      "content": "{\"siteTitle\":\"Angular Material\",\"WeaveVersion\":\"0.1\",\"editorFontSize\":\"14\",\"description\":\"Angular Material Test\",\"author\":\"Someone\"}"
    }
  }
}
var data = {
  "files": files
};
var jsonSets = JSON.parse(data.files.files["settings.json"].content);

console.log(jsonSets.siteTitle);
```